# Prove that the orbital projection of a $G$-space $X$ is a functional cover

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

What shown to follow is a reference from the text *Curso de Topología* by Sergey A. Antonyan. I traslated it from spanish and thus for sake of completeness I put [here](https://academicos.fciencias.unam.mx/wp-content/uploads/sites/94/2016/08/Notas-Topologia.pdf) a link where you can find the original text: in particular to follow I summarise the pages $234$-$236$ and the definition given at the page $258$.

> **Definition**
>
> Let be $G$ a group and let be $X$ a topological space. If we equipe $G$ with the discrete topology then an action of $G$ on $X$ is a continuous function $\theta:G\times X\rightarrow X$ such that
>
> 1. $\theta(g\cdot h,x)=\theta\big(g,\theta(h,x)\big)$ for any $g,h\in G$ and for any $x\in X$
> 2. $\theta(e,x)=x$ for any $x\in X$ where $e$ is the identity element of $G$.
>
> So we call $X$ with the action $\theta$ $G$-space.
>
> To follow we are indicating $\theta(g,x)$ as $gx$ and thus for any $g\in G$ we define a function $\tilde g:X\rightarrow X$ by letting that
> $$
> \tilde g(x)=gx
> $$
> for any $x\in X$ and we call it translation.
>
> **Proposition**
>
> Let be $X$ a $G$-space. For any $g\in G$ the translation is a hoemomorphism.
>
> *Proof*. Omitted.
>
> So we define a function $\Gamma$ from $G$ to the group $\hom(X)$ of homeomorphisms in $X$ by letting that
> $$
> \Gamma(g):=\tilde g
> $$
> for any $g\in G$.
>
> **Proposition**
>
> The function $\Gamma$ is a homomorphism.
>
> *Proof*. Omitted.
>
> **Definition**
>
> An action $\theta$ is said effective if the homomorphism $\Gamma$ is injective, that is if $\tilde g=\text{id}_X$ then $g=e$.
>
> **Definition**
>
> The action of $G$ in $X$ is said independent if for any $g\in G\setminus\{e\}$ there exist $x\in X$ such that $gx\neq x$.
>
> Clearly any independent action if effective.
>
> **Definition**
>
> If $X$ is a $G$-space then the set
> $$
> G(x):=\{gx:g\in G\}
> $$
> for any $x\in X$ is said orbit of $x$.
>
> **Proposition**
>
> If $G(x)\cap G(y)\neq\emptyset$ then $G(x)=G(y)$ and so the orbits determine a partition of $X$.
>
> *Proof*. Omitted
>
> The function $p:X\rightarrow X/G$ given by
> $$
> p(x):=G(x)
> $$
> for any $x\in X$ is surjective and it is called orbital projection and in particular if we equipped the set $X/G$ with the quotient topology we call it orbital space.
>
> **Proposition**
>
> The orbital projection of a $G$-space is a continuous and open function.
>
> *Proof*. Omitted.
>
> **Definition**
>
> A $G$-space $X$ is said discontinuous if any $x\in X$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $gU\cap hU=\emptyset$ if $g$ and $h$ are two distinct elements of $G$. In particular the neighborhood $U$ is said lock neighborhood.
>
> **Definition**
>
> Let be $X$ and $Y$ two topological spaces and let be $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a continuous and surjective funciton. So we say that $f$ is a functional cover if for any $y\in Y$ there exists a neighborhood $V_y$ and a collection $\mathcal U:=\{U_i:i\in I\}$ of open and disjoint sets in $X$ such that $f^{-1}[V]$ is disjoint union of these sets and such that the function $f|_{U_i}$ is a homeomorphism.
>
> **Theorem**
>
> The orbital projection of a $G$-space $X$ is a functional cover.
>
> **Proof**. Let be $x$ a poin of $X$ and thus let be $U$ a lock neighborhood. So since $p$ is open then $p[U]$ is an open set of $G(x)=p(x)\in X/G$. Then
> $$
> p^{-1}\big[p[U]\big]=\bigcup_{g\in G}gU
> $$
> so that $\mathcal G:=\{gU:g\in G\}$ is a collection of open and disjoint set of $X$ whose union is $p^{-1}\big[p[U]\big]$ and clearly the function $p|_{gU}$ is for any $g$ a hoemomorphsim.

So I did not understand why $p|_{gU}$ is for any $g$ a hoemomorphsim and thus I ask to explain it: in particular I know that it is open and continuous so that the statement follows showing that it is injective but unfortunately I do not be able to do it. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Hint:  If $p(x) = p(y)$ with $x,y\in gU$, then there is an $h\in G$ for which $h x = y$.  Then try to show that $y\in gU \cap (hg)U$, which contradicts the fact that $U$ is a lock neighborhood unless $h$ is the identity element of $G$.  As an aside: the definition of "independent" ("libre" ?) is different from the one in the text you linked.  In the text, it is "for all $x\in X$", not "there exists $x\in X$". This is usually called a free action.  Also, 'functional covering" is more commonly called a "covering" or "covering map".

Comment: @JasonDeVito So if $p(x)=p(y)$ then $y\in G(x)$ and thus there exist $h\in g$ such that $h\ast x=y$ but  $x\in gU$ so that $y=g\xi$ for some $\xi\in U$ thus $y=hx=h(g\xi)=(hg)\xi$
that means $y\in(hg)U$ and thus $gU\cap(hg)U\neq\emptyset$ that is impossible unless $h=e$. So did I apply your arguments correctely? Then you correctely said: *independet* is my traslation for *libre*. Excuse me for the mistake but I di not know how eanglish speaker call a *libre espacio*.

Comment: Perfect!  And as for *libre*, I hope you didn't take offense - I was just trying to help.  (I'm actually trying to learn some conversational spanish and I plan on using the notes you linked to to try to upgrade that to learning some mathematical Spanish.  Thanks!)

Comment: @JasonDeVito Oh, do not worry! I did not take offense: I am autodidact and thus any advice is well accepted and so if you could help me other times I will very grateful to you. Well if in the next days I have some difficult can I ask your assistance? In particular I am studing some algebraic topology beacuse I have to study the exact and closed form in differential geometry.

Comment: You are, of course, welcome to ask.  I'm not sure when/if I'll have time to respond.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Oh, thanks to much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if $p(x)=p(y)$ then $y\in G(x)$ and thus there exist $h\in G$ such that $h\ast y=y$ but $x\in gU$ so that there must exit $\xi\in U$ such that $y=g\xi$ and thus $y=hx=h(g\xi)$ that means $y\in(hg)U$ so that
$$
gU\cap(hg)U\neq\emptyset
$$
and clearly this is impossible unless $h=e$.